# tinydtls configuration in Contiki

Tags: gcc, makefile, contiki

I am currently trying to configure [tinydtls](https://github.com/particle-iot/tinydtls) as described in the [README](https://github.com/particle-iot/tinydtls/blob/master/README) in order to later include it into an application, or at least, make the examples run.

The first steps, including the resulting warnings:

```
home/name/contiki/apps/tinydtls$ autoreconf
```

> aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'

```
home/name/contiki/apps/tinydtls$ ./configure --with-contiki

home/name/contiki/apps/tinydtls$ make
```

*with both TARGET=native and TARGET=zoul*

The compilation always ends with (many) undefined reference errors:

```
obj_zoul/dtls.o: In function dtls_add_ecdsa_signature_elem':
dtls.c:(.text.dtls_add_ecdsa_signature_elem+0x10): undefined reference to `dtls_ec_key_from_uint32_asn1'
```

*dtls_ec_key_from_uint32_asn1* is located in *contiki/apps/tinydtls/crypto.c*.
Adding *#include crypto.h* in dtls.c doesn't fix the problem, but *#include crypto.c* does (fix this first error). Accordingly I assume the problem must have to do something with the linking.

How should the Makefile, of which I pasted a (hopefully significant) part under this question, be adjusted?

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
MKDIR = mkdir
ETAGS = /bin/false

prefix = /usr/local
exec_prefix = ${prefix}
abs_builddir = /home/name/contiki/apps/tinydtls
top_builddir = .
libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir = ${prefix}/include/tinydtls
package = tinydtls-0.8.2

install := cp

# files and flags
SOURCES:= dtls.c crypto.c ccm.c hmac.c netq.c peer.c dtls_time.c session.c
ifneq ("", "1")
SOURCES += debug.c
endif
SUB_OBJECTS:=aes/rijndael.o  ecc/ecc.o sha2/sha2.o
OBJECTS:= $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES)) $(SUB_OBJECTS)
HEADERS:=dtls.h hmac.h debug.h dtls_config.h uthash.h numeric.h crypto.h global.h ccm.h \
 netq.h t_list.h alert.h utlist.h prng.h peer.h state.h dtls_time.h session.h \
 tinydtls.h
CFLAGS:=-Wall -pedantic -std=c99 
CPPFLAGS:= -DDTLSv12 -DWITH_SHA256 -DDTLS_CHECK_CONTENTTYPE
SUBDIRS:=tests doc platform-specific sha2 aes ecc
DISTSUBDIRS:=$(SUBDIRS) examples/contiki
DISTDIR=$(top_builddir)/$(package)
FILES:=Makefile.in configure configure.in dtls_config.h.in tinydtls.h.in \
  Makefile.tinydtls $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS)
LIB:=libtinydtls.a
LDFLAGS:=
ARFLAGS:=cru
doc:=doc
```

Edit: Changed the directory for this post to /home/name/...

Edit2: Added warnings after 'autoreconf'.

Comment: I just tried this and was not able to reproduce the exact problem you describe. I'm a bit suspicious about the directory name `...` - TIL that it's possible to create such a directory in Linux, though I wonder what's the motivation? Maybe it confuses the toolchain.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I changed the directory's name in order to hide my ubuntu-username at stackoverflow. The real directory doesn't include /.../.

Comment: The warning about `configure.in` *vs*. `configure.ac` is insignificant to you.  The tinydtls maintainers really ought to get with the program, as it has been a very long time since Autoconf changed the standard name of its input file, but the warning does not convey any kind of issue with finding or processing the file.